# Placing image based banner ads without affecting SEO

Tags: seo, advertising

I have a website where I must place a banner ad. It's not an iframe or JS code like an AdSense ad. It is a simple jpg/png file that I need to add to a Bootstrap site and link another site. So my question is that how should I do this if I want to respect every Google SEO guides?

Do I need to just simply link the image with a `nofollow` tag? Or do I need to link the image with a Javascript code? Which is the common solution, what would be your choice? My only goal is to don't do anything that can be bad for SEO. I just want to simply display an ad and get an advantage from the clicking users. I don't want to transfer link juice, I don't even wait any benefits from the linking, except the users who click on the ad.

Answer (score 2):

You should place the banner image inside a `picture` tag which will itself be inside a `figure` tag. This is to properly (SEO-wise) structure your banner mark up.

The aforementioned mark up will then need to be placed inside an `aside` tag to mark it as non-main content, since it is an ad.

Regarding the `nofollow`, it is up to you. If you don't want search engines to follow the link, by all means add it.

More info regarding the mentioned tags:

[HTML picture tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)

[HTML figure tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp)

[HTML aside tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp)

Keep in mind that you will need to have various sizes of the image file, each for different screen sizes, each time serving the one that fits best. Also, having an alt tag is very important.

As a final note, `figure` tag is only needed if you also need to add text alongside the image. If you need just to serve the banner you may omit it and just use `picture` inside `aside`.